# Update user password via REST Drupal 8.x

Tags: php, rest, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8.3.x.

The simple requirnment is like, user need to update his password by entering his old and new password.

By Google I found [this link](http://www.qed42.com/blog/restful-drupal-primer) and using it but ***I am not understand how to send new password?***

**HTTP request is like this.**

Method:

```
PATCH
```

HEADER:

```
Authorization:Bearer <token>
Content-Type:application/hal+json
```

Body:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "type": {
            "href": "{domain}/rest/type/user/user"
        }
    },
    "pass": [
        {"existing":"testpass"}
    ]
}
```

**Now how to set new password here?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Analogously](http://www.qed42.com/blog/restful-drupal-primer) to updating mail action

> ```
> {
>  "_links": {
>    "type": {
>      "href": "{domain}/rest/type/user/user"
>    }
>  },
>  "pass":[{"existing":"testpass"}],
>  "mail":{
>    "value":"updatedtestuser@mailserver.com"
>  }
> }
> ```

it should be sth like

```
{
    "_links": {
        "type": {
            "href": "{domain}/rest/type/user/user"
        }
    },
    "pass": [
        {"existing":"testpass", "value": "newpass"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've tested this solution and it works but it doesn't actually need the existing password, if I enter only the new one it still changes it and doesn't do a verify on the actual password. I know this post is a bit old but thats the only thing I've found about it, is there a better way to do what I'm looking for?